# python 3.8 context help while mouse cursor is pointing to method or function

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I move cursor over a method using my mouse inside Pycharm, a very detailed context help is shown. Can someone explain how to understand/read this particular example?
Below I moved cursor over "sorted" method which I belive is built-in function.

```
builtins 
@overload
def sorted(__iterable: Iterable[_T],
           *,
           key: (_T) -> _SupportsLessThan,
           reverse: bool = ...) -> List[_T]
Possible types:
• (__iterable: Iterable[_LT], Any, key: None, reverse: bool) -> List[_LT]
• (__iterable: Iterable[_T], Any, key: (_T) -> _SupportsLessThan, reverse: bool) -> List[_T]
Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.
```

For example, _T , -> , _LT , reverse: .... what do these things mean?

Comment: You get the signature of possible functions, and a short descriptions. `_T` is the type of your data (just because `key` must be compatible with the same time. You may see documentation about Python typing annotation in https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html , but it is an advanced topic, and type annotation are optional

Answer (score 0):

Let' break down the function signature. This function receive 3 arguments. The name of the first argument is `__iterable`, and it is followed by`: Iterable[_T]`. This syntax is to specify [typing annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which is optional and not really enforced by python. But these typing annotations can be quite useful and checked with tools such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

After the `:` following the argument name you get the type of that argument. It can be a specific type like `int`, `str`, `YourClass`, etc.. But often we need more flexibility. Instead of limiting the type to be just `list`, for instance, often the function can can accept anything that we can iterate on. To specify this king of type the `typing` module provides several options. In this case `Iterable` is used. This is a "generic type", since the actual elements in it also have a type. The `_T` here is only a placeholder. By using `_T` also in the `key` argument you are saying that the type of `key` is related to the type returned by iterating over `__iterable`.

The syntax in `key: (_T) -> _SupportsLessThan` can be strange at first, but what it means is that `key` is a function (the parenthesis are the clue here) and this function receives a single argument of type `_T`. That is, this function receives the same type that you get when you iterate over `__iterable`. The `-> _SupportsLessThan` part is specifying the return type of this function. All it is saying is that the type of whatever this function returns must support comparison with the `<` operator.

The `-> List[_T]` is specifying the return type of the `sorted` function. Note again the use of `_T`. In the end, from reading the signature and without looking at the source code of this function of executing it, you know exactly what it expects as arguments and you know exactly what it returns.

Comment: Sure, no problem,. If you think this fully answers your question then accept the answer. Unless you think your question is not fully answered. In that case you can comment here for either me to add the extra information, or for someone else to write another answer.